# Connecting to Hive from intellij

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, intellij-idea, hive

I have Hive tables populating data from a hadoop server. Now I want to connect to existing HIVE tables from my  scala spark code which is running on local intellij.

I tried copying hive-site.xml into my local system and adding the file into my class path and trying to access the hive tables. But it always comes back with error

> org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Table not found .

Is there any code snippet or configuration set up that I can douse to access an existing HIVE table from my local scala spark code?

Comment: _"adding the file into my class path"_ >> it's the **directory** that must be added to the driver's CLASSPATH, not the file itself...

Comment: Thanks a lot !!! It worked when I added metastore_db folder as "Resource Root"

Comment: Hi, Could you please let me know how to access hive table from local pyCharm??